# Create Successful and Fail messages using try and catch on phpMyAdmin 5.5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a try and catch for mysql query so that when insert statement is successful return a statement "Successfully Inserted" and if not successful then return error message "Failed to Insert". I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you trying to create a try/catch in an sql function or in php? Are you trying to do this through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I created a Stored Procedure which does 3 transactions. 

1. Insert an xml block into a column in a database called Collected_events 
2. Parse the xml block and extract the values base on tags
3. Insert the values extracted from the xml into a new database called Crunch.

I'm doing this using phpmyadmin and I need to implement a way to return successful if the entire stored procedure executes successfully and if not then return stored procedure failed.